# Twig\Error\SyntaxError Message: Unexpected token "name" of value "is_negotiable" ("end of statement block" expected)

Tags: twig, slim-3, twig-extension

twig code -  I have created one checkbox for is_negotiable variable. I want to read the value of checkbox and print the message on frontend whether it is negotiable or not .

---

```
<tr>
    <td id="is-negotiable"> 
    {% if '{{objProductDetails['is_negotiable']}} == 1' %} 
        <p>Negotiable</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Not Negotiable</p>
    {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

Comment: u don't need those single quotes around the statement

Comment: I removed that quotes but it shows the error. Twig\Error\SyntaxError
Message: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".

Comment: `if objProductDetails['is_negotiable'] == 1`

Answer (score 3):

do it simply as:

```
<td id="is-negotiable"> 
    {% if objProductDetails.is_negotiable == 1 %} 
        <p>Negotiable</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Not Negotiable</p>
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

when you're in the `{% %}` block, you are already accessing variables the same way as in `{{ }}` block